# Multiple if statements in C 446

Tags: c

Anyone know the problem? It only detects the first character. I don't know the problem, please help. I can't find the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int password;

    printf("Enter your password. \n");
    printf("Password must contain an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, and a           number. \n");
    scanf("%c", &password);

    if( isupper(password) ){
        printf("Password meets requirement 1. \n");
    }
    if( islower(password) ){
        printf("Password meets requirement 2. \n");
    }
    if( isdigit(password) ){
        printf("Password meets requirement 3. \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/ZdDHgpx8

Comment: `isupper`, `islower`, and `isdigit` operate on single characters, not strings.

Comment: you are reading a single character into an int variable that should be a password. Thats not how you use scanf, integer variables, or passwords.

Comment: try `scanf("%s", &password);`   notice `%s` instead of `%c`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `password` is a single entity, it can only store a single character. You also *read* a single character. [This `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might help.

If you want to read multiple characters you need to use the `"%s"` format, and you also need an *array* of characters. Like

```
char password[32];
scanf("%31s", password);
```

The `"%31s"` format tells [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read at most 31 characters and store as a zero-terminated string (hence only reading at most 31 characters to store in a 32 character array).

---

Then for the other code, you need to use *loops* to iterate over the string. Here you have two choices when it comes to know the end of the string: Either use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the length of the string, or rely on the fact that strings in C are terminated by a zero (character `'\0'`).

Answer (score 0):

You only read a single character and then you use functions to test this single character. Read into a *char buffer* (e.g. `char password[128]` using `fgets(password, 128, stdin)`) and then loop over your password and test *each* of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You've used an int and are storing the ascii value of the first character entered in it. Instead you should a character array(char[]) or a character pointer(char*) and allocate memory to it and then use %s in scanf(instead of %c) to capture the entered password.